# Calling Sys.argv in Print Command in Python

Tags: python-2.6, sys

I am a beginner programmer and i can't get this. Trying to print Sys.argv. I have the PRINT command set in script which should call sys.argv.

how do i run : `python test.py device1`

what i have tried :

```
print ('please Check' + sys.argv[1]_config.txt )
```

Current Output :

```
please Check + sys.argv[1]+_config.txt
```

what i am looking for :

```
print " please check device1_config.txt
```

Any Idea how to do this?

Comment: In test.py , did you use `from __future__ import print_function` to use that python3.x style print function?

Comment: No, i havent imported that module ..

Comment: what does that do and how can i use that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for a in range(len(sys.argv)):
    # print(a)
    if 'device' in sys.argv[a]:
        print('please check device1_config.txt ')
```

Or to include it as a variable:

```
for a in range(len(sys.argv)):
    # print(a)
    if 'device' in sys.argv[a]:
        dev = sys.argv[a]
        print('please check {}_config.txt '.format(dev))
```

Comment: if i run python test.py device2 , will it print "please check device2_config.txt"  ??

Comment: i ran the second part , it didn't print anything...however it didnt give me error either...

Comment: is script is executable and do you have the shebang path at the top? 

example:
#!/usr/bin/python 
or on windows 
#!python